# How to detect EditText got focus by Android. Not by end-user touching on the edit text?

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, onfocus, autofocus

An [android.widget.EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) can get focus by 2 reasons as I know:

**Case 1**. End-users touch on the edit text by purpose.

**Case 2**. The system give the Edit Text automatically.

- Navigation
- First default focus
- ...

**My question is:**  **How to I detect Case 2 ONLY**? ( Event listener?)

The reason I want to detect case 2 is: I want to set current position is the last position IF the edit text get focus by Case 2.

EditText.setOnFocusChangeListener is for both case1, case2 so It seems that I can't use this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Updated**
 Implement `android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener` in your activity (for example)
and set `yourView.setOnFocusChangeListener(yourActivity)`
If you combine it with `OnTouchListener` then you can filter out user touches since onTouch() is called first - you may set boolean class member. Make sure to reset that boolean when focus is lost.

The code should be somewhat like this:

```
...
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;

...

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener, OnTouchListener {

    boolean userTouchedView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(...) {
        ...
        yourView.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus && !userTouchedView)) {
            //YOUR CASE 2
        }
        else if(!hasFocus)
            userTouchedView=false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(v==yourView){
            userTouchedView=true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This will work with both case 1 & case 2. What I want is Case 2 only. Thanks!